# Correlation between variables using numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would need to calculate the correlation between the presence of uppercase, special punctuation, specific words, in texts labelled as fake/not fake.

For example:

```
Text      Label        Uppercase       Special Punctuation    Specific Word
text1       1                1                       0                   1
text2       0                0                       0                   0
text3       1                1                       1                   1
text4       1                1                       1                   1
text5       0                0                       0                   1
```

Uppercase, Special Punctuation and Specific Word can take only one of these two values: 1 or 0.
I would like to determine the correlation between these features related to the label (fake=1/not fake=0). I thought to use Pearson correlation as follows

```
import numpy as np

# Create correlation matrix
corr_matrix = df.corr().abs()
```

May I ask you if this the right function to use or if there are different correlation functions in python that calculate the correlation between binary variables?

Comment: `.corr()` should work if you have numeric values. Are these variables strings?

Comment: not, they are boolean values. Only text is string. Label is a binary variable and my target variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is correct, but I don't understand why you're using only absolute values. The sign of the correlation is informative for the direction of the association. I'm not familiar with your context so I'll just flag this without going any further.

Correlation can be calculated in subtly different ways, i.e. 'pearson', 'kendall', 'spearman'. The default method is 'pearson'. You can calculate using other methods by specifying the 'method' argument. Like this:

```
corr_matrix = df.corr(method = 'kendall')
```

more information can be found in the documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html

Comment: thanks, annicheez, could you please tell me what you mean that I am taking absolute values? If you refer to 0 and 1 in punctuation, uppercase, ... , they are indicator of the presence or absence in the text of ! or ATTENTION, for example.

Comment: Your code suggests you are converting all of your values to positive: "df.corr().abs()".

Comment: I see. thanks anncheez. One question. In your code, but also in Muhammet 's one, there is no information about the target variable, i.e. Label. How can I know that the correlation is between the other variables and the target?

Comment: The function does not take a target variable because it returns a correlation matrix between all (numeric type) variables in the dataframe. The cell corresponding to the intersection of the two variables you're interested in will contain the correlation value you're after. For instance, if you're interested in the correlation between Label and Uppercase, you can retrieve it like this "df.corr().Label.loc['Uppercase']".

Answer (score 0):

`.corr()` should work if you have numeric values.

If your variables are strings, just convert them into integers and use correlation.
This should work:

```
df[['Uppercase','Special Punctuation', 'Specific Word']].astype(int).corr()
```

Comment: there is no information about the target variable, i.e. Label. How can I know that the correlation is between the other variables and the target?